# Laravel-toastr notification is not working after host in a live server

Tags: laravel-8, toastr

I am using laravel-8 and follow [this](https://github.com/brian2694/laravel-toastr) to use toastr message in my project. Same code is uploaded on live server. But tostr message is not working on live server where working on local. How to fix it?

In console, it says

> This page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.bootcss.com/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use link which is `https` or you can allow mixed content in order to solve your issue. Add below line in your `header`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: it works when add https.

Answer (score 0):

This page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.bootcss.com/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).